# How to split a number in a filename in Linux?

Tags: linux

I have this file name:

```
 ABCD1B02.C50.N1995009.2019353.dat
```

I would like to extract the final 7 numbers and put space like this

```
       extr=2019 353;
```

Comment: what have you tried? What tools do you need/expect to use? You're expected to show your best attempt to solve your problem. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash script:

```
fname='ABCD1B02.C50.N1995009.2019353.dat'
extr="${fname:${#fname}-11:4} ${fname:${#fname}-7:3}"
```